# f:ajax doesn't fire for onevent begin event

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

I have a `f:ajax` with `onevent="checkStatus"` with the following implementation:

```
function checkStatus(event){
    if (event.status == "begin") {
        console.log("ajax begin");
    }  else if (event.status == "success") {
        console.log("ajax success");
    }
}
```

The `f:ajax` definition is (simplified):

```
<f:ajax event='click' onevent='checkStatus` listener="#{mrBean.handler}"/>
```

The 'begin' event doesn't fire ever.
Any Idea?

**P.S** The `success` event does fire.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with Mojarra 2.1.1 on Tomcat 7.0.12 using Firefox 4.0.1 and Chrome 11. What JSF, server and browser impl/version are you using?

Comment: @BalusC - chrome dev, JSF 2.0 (myfaces), Tomcat 6.0.
I thought that maybe I was doing something wrong.

Comment: "JSF 2.0" is too generic. It's just the API version. What impl? Mojarra or MyFaces? What impl version? Mojarra 2.0.5 FCS or something?

Comment: Oh well, I don't use it. I'd try [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) instead. If it works and you'd like to stick to MyFaces for some reason, then report the issue to MyFaces boys.

Comment: ok. I'll give it a try. I don't really have any preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in MyFaces 2.0.5: [MYFACES-3080](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3080)

You can fix this by patching the jsf.js as stated in the issue comments or wait for 2.0.6 to be released.